# Working with versions on Jenkins Pipeline Shared Libraries

Tags: jenkins, groovy, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline, multiple-versions

I'm trying to figure it out on **how to work with a specific version of a Shared Library**.

`Jenkins` documentation about this isn't quite clear so I've being making some experimenting but with no success.

They basically say:

[image]

But **how should I configure `somelib` on 'Global Pipeline Libraries' section under *Manage Jenkins > System Config* menu** so I can use any of the available stable versions?!

The thing is:
Imagine that I've my `somelib` Project under version control and, currently, I've released 2 stable versions of it: `v0.1` and `v0.2` (so I have 2 tags named `v0.1` and `v0.2`).

And in some Pipeline I want to use `somelib`'s version `v0.1` and on another Pipeline I need to use `v0.2` version.

How can I do this using the `@Library` annotation provided by Jenkins?

Answer (score 7):

In the **Global Pipeline Libraries** under *Jenkins > System Config* you only set the default library version to use if not specified otherwise inside the `Jenkinsfile`. This might look like this (ignore the `Failed to connect to repo` error here):

[image]

Inside the `Jenkinsfile` you can explicitly specify which version you want to use if you do not want the default:

```
@Library('somelib@<tag/branch/commitRef>')
```

That way you can freely choose at any time which pipeline version to use for you project.

Comment: Oh right! Things now make sense.
Thanks a lot for your kindly help @fishi

Answer (score 2):

Following @fishi response I just want to leave an **important note**.

During **library configuration** on **Global Pipeline Libraries** you must **select `Modern SCM` option** so things can work seamlessly.

If you select `Legacy Mode` instead you'll not be able to use the library as desired.

If for some reason `Modern SCM` does not appear in the `Retrieval Mode` option it means that you need to upgrade `Global Pipeline Libraries` plugin or even `Jenkins`

Comment: Loading libraries with Legacy SCM is working as expected for me. At least for folder-level shared libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Basically **"Version"** is the branch name for the repo which stores the shared library codes. If you don't have any branch other than **main** or **master**, make sure to fill it in **Default Version** in your **Global Pipeline Library** configuration